# Paramiko throwing "Invalid Key" in unpad

Tags: ssh, paramiko, ssh-keygen

I'm using a tool that uses paramiko to connect via SSH to a server(s).

The tool requires me to create SSH keys, and after much trying and testing, I've arrived at this potion:

```
ssh-keygen -f my-key -o -t ed25519 -N ""
```

For reference, I'm using `-o` because the tool expects `OPENSSH` keys. The `-t ed25519` is because it expects that format. `-N ""` is because it expects unencrypted keys.

Now, paramiko is throwing this exception:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 152, in _parse_signing_key_data
    message = Message(unpad(private_data))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 40, in unpad
    raise SSHException("Invalid key")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Invalid key
```

The code that throws the exception appears to be [this](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/ed25519key.py#L40), but I don't know how to resolve this issue... Any ideas what this padding stuff is about?

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2018 (and paramiko version 2.4.2), an `Invalid key` exception is raised when a passphrase fails to decrypt an ed25519 key.

You may not even realize paramiko is attempting to decrypt an ed25519 key.

For example, if an application gives paramiko an RSA key file and a matching passphrase, and the remote server rejects that RSA key, then paramiko will silently look for an ed25519 key at `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`.  If that key file exists, and if the passphrase you provided fails to decrypt this key, you will get the `Invalid key` error.

Other than deleting `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` (yuck!!), I do not know of an easy workaround.

For more details, please see:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1305

Update:

I have discovered an additional bug.  Any ed25519 key with a comment of certain lengths also causes the "Invalid key" exception.  For details, please see:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1306